# Chrome no longer displays prototypal information about JS objects

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the old version of Chrome browsers, the developer tools/JS console displays the prototypal information about the object you create in the console.

As I've tried the latest version of Chrome, that type of info is no longer displayed. Is there any setting to tweak so that it will display the prototype information of the on-the-fly JS objects I've created in the console? Or is this a feature unnecessary in the latest version of Chrome Dev Tools?

All I want is to see a hierarchy of objects where other objects have been derived. Any suggestions?

BTW, here's some pictures of what I'm talking about:

**older version of Chrome Dev Tools:**
[image: Old version of Chrome displays information about JS objects]

*(Pic above is taken from Apress JavaScript Programmer's Reference book)*

(See the prototype hierarchy above in older version)

**latest version of Chrome Dev Tools:**
[image: Newer version of Chrome seems to display little info about JS objects]

(No more hierarchy in latest versions)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried console.dir(myGrandChild) or any object, console.log is not really meant to give you all that info, console.dir is what you should use for displaying all properties. Using console.dir will give you what you expected from before. This will be more helpful to understand: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api and http://daker.me/2013/12/devtools-console-from-novice-to-ninja.html

Comment: Correct. Few minutes ago I was able to discover console.dir() to see the hierarchy. I'm just expecting that this will be a default setting in Chrome dev tools when checking/peeking at JS objects.

Comment: It's not default anymore as they are adding more robust features, so you have to explicitly ask for the object to be display in such way, this is mostly for performance reasons. If you try other browsers, such as Firefox, using console.dir is the only way for you to get to the object properties, so this is a good change as it more standardize.